# How to integerate Facebook chat in iPhone using xmpp framework

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios4, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to integrate Facebook chat in iPhone, when I searched related stuff I found xmpp framework. I download it and run but it is not showing anything. Is there any tutorial available for this? can anyone help me to how to integerate facebook chat in iPhone?

Inam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: <strike>http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/FacebookChatHowTo</strike>

Now the project has moved to git hub, the same page can ben found on http://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/FacebookChatHowTo

Comment: clicked this URL but appear some error: Page "FacebookChatHowTo" Not Found

Select an existing page from the project's list.

Comment: I answered this in 2011, now the project has moved to git hub, the same page can ben found on https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/FacebookChatHowTo

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework
how to compile is on this link.

https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS
which is also on the same git page.

download xmppframework and unzip it.In the unzip folder contains xcode folder open it and again it contains iphoneXMPP folder ans open it click on xcode proj and run it.

login page will be displayed before that open appdelegate.m file there is delegate method:

```
(void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender willSecureWithSettings:(NSMutableDictionary *)settings
{

}
```

Replace server domain from "talk.google.com" to "chat.facebook.com" and virtualDomain from "gmail.com" to "facebook.com"

You must login with your facebook username and password.Remember username is differ from regular username,
for example 
my regular username is:" venkat.varra@gmail.com" but if i provide this wouldnot login intead of this i will provide username as: "venkat.reddy.73157203@chat.facebook.com"

password is asusual.

Toget your username like this go to facebook account and click your display name then observe address bar of the browser.

I tried this way and i get my facebook friends.You try this.

Comment: I have tried what ever you said but its not working for i am getting the following in my console--------> iPhoneXMPP[1323:60b] iPhoneXMPPAppDelegate: xmppStreamDidDisconnect:withError:
2014-04-03 22:49:01:013 iPhoneXMPP[1323:60b] Unable to connect to server. Check xmppStream.hostName

Comment: i also tried similar to what you have said but in that example it showing the following error -----> Error connecting: (null)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook seems to have deprecated `XMPP Chat API`. Should no longer work After April 30th, 2015.

More here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat#platauth